# Linq Count where IDs are different

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have the following DB-Structure: Please ignore where it says NULL

[image]

So now I want to use Linq to count where the `DateAndTimeDateType.Day` Field equals a given value and where the `EventID` is different.

Example:

So from `DateAndTimeID` 11 to 15, the day is 22.03.2019 and the `EventID` is the same for all of them. Now I want to count where the ID is different. So in this case the result should be 1.

At the moment I'm just counting where the Day is the same like shown in following code:

```
@Model.DateAndTimes
    .Where(f => f.DateAndTimeDateType.Value.DayOfYear == renderedDayWithTime.DayOfYear)
    .Count()
```

Comment: use a distinct with the correct  groupby?

Comment: @pix whats that?

Comment: @OwenPauling I was just about to give this link :) and another for the GroupBy linq method.

Comment: You can also use DistinctBy from MoreLINQ nuget

Comment: This is not a duplicate (at least not of the specified question) as the operation here is of filtering and there is no need of grouping..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After filtering for the date you could project the `EventID` and then use [`.Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var count = @Model.DateAndTimes
    .Where(f => f.DateAndTimeDateType.Value.DayOfYear == renderedDayWithTime.DayOfYear)
    .Select(f => f.EventID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

Note that if indeed you want to do this for all/a range of `DayOfYear` values then the way to go is to first `GroupBy` and then for each group have a distinct count

In addition, if indeed you have date from more than a single year you probably want to use `.Date` instead of `.DatOfYear`. This will give you the dates without the times.

Comment: I guess OP want to compare Date not only year. please correct me if I am wrong. This statement *So from DateAndTimeID 11 to 15, the day is 22.03.2019 and the eventid is the same for all of them*

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar - possibly true. Added a sentence about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
var givenDateTime = DateTime.Now; //Your date and time
var count = @Model.DateAndTimes
            .Where(f => f.DateAndTimeDateType.Value.Date == givenDateTime.Date)
            .Select(x => x.EventId)
            .Distinct()
            .Count();
```

Here we consider that, Your `f.DateAndTimeDateType.Value` is of type `DateTime` and you want to check *only date*.